# Huge performance difference between very similar queries

Tags: performance, oracle, explain

I am having an hard time in wrapping my head around some huge performance differences between two similar queries. Query #1:

```
SELECT a.waferid,
  a.channelid,
  b.originalname,
  b.translatedname,
  a.seriesdata
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM T_RT_WAFERDATA s WHERE s.waferid IN (686)
  ) a,
  T_RT_EQUIPMENTCHANNELS b
WHERE a.channelid = b.channelid
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT a.waferid,
  a.channelid,
  b.originalname,
  b.translatedname,
  a.seriesdata
FROM t_rt_waferdata a,
  T_RT_EQUIPMENTCHANNELS b
WHERE a.waferid IN (686)
AND a.channelid  = b.channelid
```

The explain plan yields the same complexity for both queries (10), and yet the second one runs roughly two orders of magnitude slower than the first one.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

edit: T_RT_WAFERDATA.waferid is PK, T_RT_EQUIPMENTCHANNELS.channelid is PK as well. T_RT_WAFERDATA is relatively big (millions of rows), while T_RT_EQUIPMENTCHANNELS is very small (hundreds).

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 2]

Comment: show us the explain plans and format your source code please.

Comment: I have reformatted the code and included images of the explain plan as returned by SQL developer

Comment: Both plans are the same. So it's unlikely that Oracle has run it according to this plans. Instead of "Explain plan", try "Autotrace", which shows what has been effectively executed.

Comment: Both plans are for second query - both have `access predicate: a.waferid-686`. Please show the plan for the first query.

Comment: Do you have any stats on buffer I/O or physical I/O or even memory usage during the HASH join phase?

Comment: Also, any chance you could prvide your execution plan with DBMS_XPLAN.Display_cursor. Not a huge fan of these execution plans from SQL Developer/Toad. All documentation I ever read on performance tuning used the former so I am used to viewing that format (and with the additional 'gather_plan_statistics' hint applied to your select statement would give you a lot more useful info). See [Oracle Base documentation on DBMS_XPLAN here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan.php)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments - How many times did you test each query? And did you wait for each query to run to completion?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, changing the form of the SQL BLOCK does nothing to the plan, Oracle is smart enough to transform the query block into the most optimal form (probably subquery unnesting here, trace the optimizer using 10053 to be sure about this).

Second, where are these plans from?  10046 tracing will give an exact answer on what plan is actually being executed, remember explain plan doesn't always retrieve the plan Oracle picks at the very last minute when real query execution happens.

Third, try running both the SQLs using `/*+GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/` and pull the plan using DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR.  Here is a nice article on how to do this: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if

And fourth, how you write your sql has nothing to do with the orders of magnitude in performance for this, I think you might be being hit by either one of the following reasons:

1.- Instance slowdown (check awr and ash reports to be sure).

2.- If you are benchmarking this by running one SQL right after another, the most likely reason is the data is cached. One way to confirm this would be doing `alter system flush buffer_cache` execute query1, then `alter system flush buffer_cache` execute query2. To rule out other forms of caching it may help to "warm up" the system by running the queries multiple times.

Please consider these two alternatives and let us know what you found out :)!